# How to initialize a multidimensional array ([][]) with no values in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So I'm writing a Maze solver, and in my maze class I'm using an array of arrays of a custom "square" object for the 2d grid of the maze.

```
public class Maze {
int height;
int width;
Square[][] grid; //2d array of squares representing the maze
Square startSquare;
Square exitSquare;

...


public static Square[][] gridMaker(int h, int w, List<Integer> squares){
 int count=0;
 Square[][] newgrid;
 for (int i=0; i<h; i++){
   for (int j=0; j<w; j++){
     Square element = new Square(squares.get(count),i,j);
     newgrid[i][j] = element;
     count++;
   }
 }
 return newgrid;
}
```

So this returns a variable not initialized error, and I understand that I only declared, and did not initialize, the newgrid variable. But, I can't figure out how to do so and I while I've read lots of posts on here about multidemensional array initialization none of them have answered my question. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Square[][] newgrid = new int[h][w];

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something really obvious.

```
Square[][] newgrid = new Square[h][w];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off what you've submitted here it looks like in your gridMaker method where you declare your 2D array newgrid you just need to instantiate it there. So, based off the rest of your code it should be:

```
Square[][] newgrid = new Square[h][w];
```

Once instantiated you should be able to assign values to indexes within the array and thus eliminate your error.